# EC2 Describe-Instance as a Automation Step Function

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I'm trying to create an Automation document that's suppose to describe the names of instances in EC2.
Here's the cli code for how to describe the names:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name, Values='MyServer*'" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value" --output text`

And here's how I converted that command to PowerShell:

`((Get-EC2Instance -Filter @{Name="tag:Name"; Values="MyServer*"}).Instances | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Tags | Where-Object -Property Key -eq Name).Value`

The results should be something like this:

`MyServer001`
`MyServer002`
`MyServer003`

[image]

I'm trying to do this as a step function in an Automation document in SSM, with the action type: aws:executeScript and using PowerShell.
Unfortunately, I got this error message:

`The term 'Get-EC2Instance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again`

Do you know if it's possible to retrieve the names of instances without targeting any instance?
Does PowerShell in AWS SSM have the capability to use the AWS PowerShell module for commands like Get-EC2Instance?

Comment: Have you installed the cmdlet? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-started.html

Comment: See following : https://myitblog.co.uk/aws/generate-an-ec2-instance-report-using-powershell/?force_isolation=true